# Why mysql query doesn't return 0 when is null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying return values 0 when field is null. For example if there is one id_articulo with importe null, the query will return 0.

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `PUJAS` (
  `ID_PUJA` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_ARTICULO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_USUARIO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIEMPO` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `IMPORTE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_PUJA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAU

LT CHARSET=latin1;
```

QUERY

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(IMPORTE),0) FROM PUJAS GROUP BY ID_ARTICULO
```

[image]

Comment: It'd be a lot better to paste in the actual SQL code than a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot 2nd argument of `IFNULL()` function

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(IMPORTE), 0) FROM PUJAS GROUP BY ID_ARTICULO
```

Comment: sorry I pasted the code bad. I tried this too, and doesn't work

Comment: And `SELECT MAX(IFNULL(IMPORTE, 0)) FROM PUJAS GROUP BY ID_ARTICULO` ?

Comment: Too, it doesn't return 0 :(

Comment: I don't understand why don't is there any 0?

Comment: Cause you select `MAX` values

Comment: How can I get return 0 when is null, using MAX? is it posible?

Comment: I don't clearly understand you. What do you mean? Using MAX you recieve the maximum value among group.

Comment: Yes, I need use MAX, because in this ID_ARTICULO, can be inserted new importe, then I get the higher value.

Comment: If there is at least one not NULL IMPORTE value in a group of rows grouped by ID_ARTICULO - it will be result of MAX function

Comment: I want get like bids, and show the higher importe. OK I will try another way then. Thanks

Comment: Si quiere, puedo explicar en espanol!. Si denre tus pujas con un articulo hay 1 que es no NULL, MAX sera equal a este puja. No zeros. :)

Comment: @jal Gracias, no tanto como quisiera :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use COALESCE ():

```
SELECT COALESCE (MAX (Importe), 0)
FROM
  ...
```

that will return the first non null value from its arguments. If MAX is null it will return 0.

EDIT

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN SUM(IMPORTE IS NULL)=0 THEN MAX(IMPORTE) ELSE 0 END
FROM
  PUJAS
GROUP BY
  ID_ARTICULO
```

This will return `MAX(Importe)` if there are no Importe for each `ID_ARTICULO` that have a null value. Otherwise it will return 0. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad1b/1).

Comment: @jal it has to work... but even your query looks correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd4e9/2

Comment: @jal what does it return? null or another value?

Comment: @jal do you want to return 0 if there's at least one row that has a null Importe?

Comment: for example if the table has got a id_articulo without importe, add 0

Comment: @jal i update my answer, but I'm not sure that i can understand your question correctly, can you provide some sample data on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

add another ifnull:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(IFNULL(IMPORTE, 0)), 0) FROM PUJAS GROUP BY ID_ARTICULO
```